# Create an object from an array of objects with custom key values

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

now I know there are a few questions that are similar like [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22378950/create-an-array-of-objects-with-custom-keys) and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40291341/create-an-array-of-objects-with-specific-key-then-remove-that-key-from-object) but neither answer my question.

Okay so...

Say I have an api call and I get a response like this

```
[
  {
     amount: 23,
     bill: 47,
     otherData: null,
     title: 'cool title'
  },
  {
     amount: 223,
     bill: 427,
     otherData: null,
     title: 'cooler title'
  },
  {
     amount: 2313,
     bill: 437,
     otherData: null,
     title: 'super cool title'
  },
  {
     amount: 123,
     bill: 147,
     otherData: null,
     title: 'coolest title'
  }
]
```

is there a way I can create a new object from this array and have custom key names using a property in the object?? so the desired output is..

```
{
  coolTitle: {
     amount: 23,
     bill: 47,
     otherData: null,
     title: 'cool title'
  },
  coolerTitle: {
     amount: 223,
     bill: 427,
     otherData: null,
     title: 'cooler title'
  },
  superCoolTitle: {
     amount: 2313,
     bill: 437,
     otherData: null,
     title: 'super cool title'
  },
  coolestTitle: {
     amount: 123,
     bill: 147,
     otherData: null,
     title: 'coolest title'
  }
}
```

now I know I can convert an array of objects into an object like so..

```
var result = {};
for (var i=0; i<array.length; i++) {
  result[array[i].key] = array[i].value;
}
```

but I have no Idea how I could get the title from each object, camelCase it and then create the custom key and the object

I'm not even sure if something like this is possible, any help would be appreciated

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the property name, extract the `title` and replace its space-characters with the upper-case character. Then, it's as simple as `reduce`-ing into an object:

```js
const input=[{amount:23,bill:47,otherData:null,title:'cool title'},{amount:223,bill:427,otherData:null,title:'cooler title'},{amount:2313,bill:437,otherData:null,title:'super cool title'},{amount:123,bill:147,otherData:null,title:'coolest title'}]

console.log(
  input.reduce((a, item) => {
    const { title } = item;
    const camel = title.replace(/ ./g, chars => chars[1].toUpperCase());
    a[camel] = item;
    return a;
  }, {})
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `map` & `reduce`, The reduce method will return the new object with custom key. Inside the reduce method use `map`. This will create an array of the value of `title` like `['cool','title']`. Inside the same map method create a string to 
convert the first character of the word to upperCase and `join` to join all the words

```js
let oldArr = [{
    amount: 23,
    bill: 47,
    otherData: null,
    title: 'cool title'
  },
  {
    amount: 223,
    bill: 427,
    otherData: null,
    title: 'cooler title'
  },
  {
    amount: 2313,
    bill: 437,
    otherData: null,
    title: 'super cool title'
  },
  {
    amount: 123,
    bill: 147,
    otherData: null,
    title: 'coolest title'
  }
]



let newArray = oldArr.reduce(function(acc, curr) {
  let crtTitle = curr.title.split(' ').map(function(item, index) {
    if (index !== 0) {
      return item.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() + item.substring(1, item.length);
    } else {
      return item;
    }

  }).join('');
  acc[crtTitle] = curr;
  return acc
}, {});
console.log(newArray)
```